# findall returning whole regular expression match as its first index even if there is one group present in it

Tags: python, regex, findall

I was using findall method using a regular expression object but i got entire expression match of my string although i had a group present in it.

I am using python 3.7.3

```
import re
def emailfinder(spam):
   emailregx=re.compile(r'''(
   [a-zA-Z0-9%_+-.]+
   @
   [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+
   (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})
   )''',re.VERBOSE)
   return emailregx.findall(spam)
print(emailfinder('tara9090@gmail.com blah monkey tanbajg@chscv.in'))
```

The output is `[('tara9090@gmail.com', '.com'), ('tanbajg@chscv.in', '.in')]`.
but i was expecting it to be `['.com','.in']`

Comment: you have two groups, perhaps the first one is typo? `r'''(` and `)'''`

Comment: http://regex101.com  - put your text and expression in and read what it does in plain text

Comment: Valid email addresses are *by far* [more complicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression) than one might think in the first place. Use a simple expression like `\S+@\S+` and actually write an email to that address.

Comment: Since you have wrapped the whole pattern with parentheses, you get the whole match, just what `re.findall` does.

Answer (score -1):

You have redundant parenthesis, resulting two groups. Fixing it works:

```
import re
def emailfinder(spam):
   emailregx=re.compile(r'''
   [a-zA-Z0-9%_+-.]+
   @
   [a-zA-Z0-9.-]+
   (\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}
   )''',re.VERBOSE)
   return emailregx.findall(spam)

print(emailfinder('tara9090@gmail.com blah monkey tanbajg@chscv.in'))
['.com', '.in']
```

Answer (score -1):

Grouping in `re` means that you want to catch only those parts. You have placed the grouping in the wrong place.

```
Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 10 2018, 22:54:23) [MSC v.1915 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9%_+-.]+\@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+(\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})')
>>> all = pattern.findall('tara9090@gmail.com blah monkey tanbajg@chscv.in')
>>> print(all)
['.com', '.in']
>>>
```